# How to Construct a Interpolating Function f(n) such that f(1)=a1, f(2)=a2, ..., f(n)=an, and f(x)=0 for all the other integer x?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, interpolation, computational-mathematics, stirling-numbers

How to construct a interpolating function f(n) such that f(1)=a1, f(2)=a2, ..., f(n)=an, and f(x)=0 for all the other integer x ?
Recently, I learn about the Stirling numbers of the second kind
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind
And find it has such an interesting property
So I wonder how to construct such function according to any given data?
Construct a f(n) satisfied f(1)=a1, f(2)=a2, ..., f(n)=an, and f(x)=0 for all the other integer x

Comment: What do you mean?  You've written down such a function.  What's left to say?

Comment: And this does not seem to be related to Stirling numbers.

Comment: Unless the point is to have a continuous function on the reals? That's sort of implied by the word interpolation, although I read it your way, too, at first, because of the request for $f(n).$ @lulu

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Ah, you are absolutely right.  I missed the "interpolating" bit, just saw the $f(n)$.

Comment: If you meant "interpolating", then I would use the piecewise linear version.  Why not?  It's simple, continuous, easy to automate...and behaves sensibly between the "known" values.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it,  you are requiring a $f\; : \;  {\mathbb R} \to {\mathbb R}$ such that $$
f(x) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {a_k } & {\left| {\;x = k \in \left\{ {1,2, \ldots ,n} \right\}} \right.}  \\
   0 & {\left| {\;x \in {\mathbb Z}\backslash \left\{ {1,2, \ldots ,n} \right\}} \right.}  \\
\end{array}} \right.
$$
If my understanding is correct, then you can take
the product of a [Boxcar function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxcar_function) of unitary value  times the polynomial interpolating $a_1 , a_2, \cdots , a_n$ .

If you are looking for a continuous function, it shall have an infinite number of zeros, so cannot be a polynomial of finite order.
In this case the boxcar can be replaced by the sum of $n$ [sinc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) functions centered at $x=1,2, \ldots, n$.

Comment: Usually, interpolation wants a continuous function, so you'd really want to interpolate $a_0=0, a_1,\dots,a_n,a_{n+1}=0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: if it was like you say then it would be a simple polynomial. But OP states that $f(n)$  should be null for $n \in {\mathbb Z}  / \{1, \ldots , n\}$

Comment: Well, I meant, your function isn't continuous. If you interpolate to a polynomial with values on $0,1,\dots,n+1$ with zeros at the end, then multiplying by the boxcar function leaves the function continuous and still having this property.